# How to get based on city using spinner from local database

Tags: android, android-sqlite, spinner, android-spinner

I have list of cities and area from server and I added them i local database. Now I want to show cities fetch from local db and based on local db I want to show area as per cities. I have done code but problem is that I am getting only one area based on city and when I select any other city and then select area then it shows me previously added area also. I am not able to work it properly.

// code for db

```
       String CREATE_CITY_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_CITY + "("
    + KEYCITY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + CITY_ID + " TEXT,"
    + CITY_NAME + " TEXT," + AREA_ID + " TEXT,"
    + AREA_NAME + " TEXT" + ")";
 db.execSQL(CREATE_CITY_TABLE);
```

// Adding new cities

```
public void addCity(CityAreaModel cityAreaModel)
 {


    SQLiteDatabase cityDb = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
     values.put(CITY_ID,cityAreaModel.getCityId());
  values.put(CITY_NAME,cityAreaModel.getCityName());
  values.put(AREA_ID,cityAreaModel.getAreaId());
    values.put(AREA_NAME,cityAreaModel.getAreaName());


// Inserting Row
  cityDb.insert(TABLE_CITY, null, values);
     cityDb.close(); // Closing database connection
 }
```

// Getting All cities

```
   public List<CityAreaModel> getAllCities() {
     List<CityAreaModel> cityList = new ArrayList<CityAreaModel>();
// Select All Query
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CITY;

SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

// looping through all rows and adding to list
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        CityAreaModel object = new CityAreaModel();

        object.setCityId(cursor.getString(1));
        object.setCityName((cursor.getString(2)));
        object.setAreaId(cursor.getString(3));
        object.setAreaName(cursor.getString(4));

        // Adding contact to list
        cityList.add(object);
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}

// return contact list
return cityList;
```

}

// Getting All area citywise

```
   public List<CityAreaModel> getAllArea(String cityId) {
List<CityAreaModel> cityList = new ArrayList<CityAreaModel>();
// Select All Query
String selectQuery = "select * from " + TABLE_ADDRESS + " where " + CITY_ID + " = '" + cityId + "'";
Log.i("adressupdate",   "getAllArea() selectQuery: " + selectQuery);
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

// looping through all rows and adding to list
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        CityAreaModel object = new CityAreaModel();

        object.setCityId(cursor.getString(1));
        object.setCityName((cursor.getString(2)));
        object.setAreaId(cursor.getString(3));
        object.setAreaName(cursor.getString(4));

        // Adding contact to list
        cityList.add(object);
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}

// return contact list
return cityList;
```

}

// code for spinner of class

```
      cityAreaModelsList = db.getAllCities();
    for (int i = 0; i < cityAreaModelsList.size(); i++) {
     cityList.add(cityAreaModelsList.get(i).getCityName());

      }


       cityAdapetr = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, cityList);
       cityAdapetr.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
  select_city.setAdapter(cityAdapetr);
    select_city.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    String cityId = (String) cityAreaModelsList.get(position).getCityId();


    areaModelList = db.getAllArea(cityId);

        List<CityAreaModel> areamodellist = new ArrayList<CityAreaModel>();
        areamodellist = db.getAllArea(cityId);

    for(int i =0;i< areamodellist.size();i++)
    {
         areaList.add(areamodellist.get(i).getAreaName());
    }


        areaAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, areaList);
        areaAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        select_location.setAdapter(areaAdapter);


}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}
```

});

```
     select_location.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

  String  areaName = (String) areaList.get(position);
    if(areaName.equals("Select Location"))
    {
        areaId = "0";
    }

    else{



        areaId = (String) areaList.get(position);

        if(areaName.equals("Vasundhara Enclave"))
        {
            areaId = "1";
        }
        else if(areaName.equals("New Ashok Nagar"))
        {
            areaId ="2";
        }
        else if(areaName.equals("Mayur Vihar-1"))
        {
            areaId = "3";
        }
        else
            areaId = "4";

    }
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}
```

});

// I am having problem while selecting city and area. Also I want to know how can I "select city" and "select area" field in top of apinner list

Comment: post logcat warning or error

Comment: no, error I want to know when I select any city from list in spinner how can I get its city Id . check my updated code

Comment: use spinner's onitemselected listener and from that you get position. not get city id from arrylist using that position

Comment: check my updated question

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using using ArrayAdapter, you may use **SimpleCursorAdapter** which save you the step to loop through the cursor into a List.

```
// after getting the cursor
SimpleCursorAdapter cityAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            context, // Activity's context or getActivity() if in a fragment
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
            cursor,
            new String[] { COL_NAME_OF_THE_CITY },
            new int[] { android.R.id.text1 },
            0);
```

and whenever you want to get the city id, you can call:

```
Cursor cursor = (Cursor) cityAdapter.getItem(selectedSipnnerPosition);
if (cursor!=null && cursor.moveToPosition(selectedSipnnerPosition)) {
    String cityId = cursor.getString(CITY_ID_COLUMN_INDEX);
}
```

Kindly note that in order to use **SimpleCursorAdapter**, you must have a BaseColumns._ID as the integer primary key in your TABLE_CITY.

Answer (score 0):

Your cityAreaModelsList not String type, but your ArrayAdapter is String type

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 select_city.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
        int position, long id) {
    // Here you get the current item (a CityModel object) that is selected by its position
    CityAreaModel model = adapter.getItem(position);
    // Here you can do the action you want to...
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ID: " + model.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter) {  
    }
});
```

you have to use a custom adapter for spinner

```
    public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CityAreaModel>{

    // Your sent context
    private Context context;
    // Your custom values for the spinner (CityAreaModel)
    private CityAreaModel[] values;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            CityAreaModel[] values) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }

    public int getCount(){
       return values.length;
    }

    public CityAreaModel getItem(int position){
       return values[position];
    }

    public long getItemId(int position){
       return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView label = new TextView(context);
        label.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        label.setText(values[position].getName());
        return label;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView label = new TextView(context);
        label.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        label.setText(values[position].getName());
        return label;
    }
}
```

use it as:

```
 private CustomAdapter adapter;

   adapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
            cityAreaModelsList);
   spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_id);
   spinner.setAdapter(adapter); /
```

Comment: u have to call `cityList.clear()`  in `getAllArea()` method before the select uesry

Answer (score 0):

for "select city" and "select area" field in top of apinner:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
groupName = (ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("groupName");

adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.spinner_item) {
                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                    View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                    if (position == getCount()) {
                        ((TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText("");
                        ((TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setHint(getItem(getCount()));
                        ((TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setHintTextColor(Color.parseColor("#999999"));
                    }
                    return v;
                }
                public int getCount() {
                    return super.getCount()-1;
                }
            };
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.selecteditem);
            adapter.addAll(groupName);
            spin.setAdapter(adapter);
            spin.setSelection(adapter.getCount());
```

spinner_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:drawableEnd="@drawable/downarrow"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/downarrow"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:textColor="#000"/>
```

selecteditem.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingStart="10dp"
    android:paddingEnd="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:checked="false" />
```